# My Partial Views don't show

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

for the first time I'm using Partial Views. On this page I have a sub menu on the left and based on what is clicked in the menu I need to show a partial view on the right.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult PersoonsgebodenGegevens(string login)
    {
        ViewData["UserName"] = TempData["loginName"];

        var LOGINNA = TempData["loginName"];
        string loginNaam = GetLoginNaam((string)LOGINNA);
        var model = new PersoneelsgegevensModel(loginNaam);

        ViewBag.PartialViewName = "_Persoonsgegevens";

        return View("PersoonsgebondenGegevens", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersoonsgebondenGegevens(string ButtonSubMenu, FormCollection FC)
    {
        ViewData["UserName"] = TempData["loginName"];

        var LOGINNA = TempData["loginName"];
        string loginNaam = GetLoginNaam((string)LOGINNA);
        var model = new PersoneelsgegevensModel(loginNaam);

        switch (ButtonSubMenu)
        {
            case "Persoonsgegevens":
                ViewBag.PartialViewName = "_Persoonsgegevens";
                break;
            case "Burgelijkestaat":
                ViewBag.PartialViewName = "_Burgelijkestaat";
                break;
            case "Diploma":
                ViewBag.PartialViewName = "_Diploma";
                break;
            case "Loopbaan/Verlof":
                ViewBag.PartialViewName = "_LoopbaanVerlof";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return View("PersoonsgebondenGegevens", model);
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PersoonsgebondenGegevens", "Home", FormMethod.Post, Html.RouteCollection == null))
{ 
if (Model.buttonJobClicked == true)
{        
    <div class="ContentLeft">
        <div class="leftpart">
            <div class="MenuHeader">Persoonsgebonden info</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="lili" id="1"><input id="button01" type="submit"   value="Persoonsgegevens" name="ButtonSubMenu" /></li>
                <li class="lili" id="2"><input id="button02" type="submit"   value="Burgelijkestaat" name="ButtonSubMenu" /></li>
                <li class="lili" id="3"><input id="button03" type="submit"   value="Diploma" name="ButtonSubMenu" /></li>
                <li class="lili" id="4"><input id="button04" type="submit"   value="Loopbaan/Verlof" name="ButtonSubMenu" /></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="leftfooter"></div> 
    </div>
}
}

<div class="rightpart">
@{
    Html.Partial((string)@ViewBag.PartialViewName);
}       
</div>
```

If I debug everything seems to be ok. The model gets passed to my Partial Views and all data get filled in correctly. But for some reason no Partial View shows in my parent view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
@{
    Html.Partial((string)@ViewBag.PartialViewName);
}
```

to

```
@Html.Partial((string)ViewBag.PartialViewName)
```

[note that you don't need the semicolon]

Comment: I'm glad. Play close attention on when to use semicolon and the '@' while using razor views. You can also vote the answer up and mark it as answered.